# Pinter's Set Theory Exercise 1.7.6: Let G and H be graphs. Prove that if G and H are sets, then G inverse and GoH are sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've managed to do a proof of this by using the previous exercise that shows the domain and range of G are both sets. Then {y} is a set as it is a subset of the range for any y in the range, and similarly for any x in the domain. So for all x and y, {y,x} is a set by being a union of {x} and {y}, and then by Axiom 5 {{y}, {y,x}} = (y,x) is a set for all x and y and the union of these is G inverse so this is also a set.

I can also do GoH similarly by breaking the sets down and reconstructing with unions. But... It's so ugly. It's all I've got but I feel like I'm not even in the right ballpark of what the intended proof is. Is there a more attractive path to this result?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

I assume that with "$G$ is a *graph*" you mean $G = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in X \text { and } y \in Y \}$ where $X,Y$ are sets.

Thus, what is $G^{-1}$ ? It is $\{ (y,x) \mid x \in X \text { and } y \in Y \}$ where $X,Y$ are sets.

So, if the condition "$x \in X \text { and } y \in Y$" allows us to use [Specification axiom schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Statement) to prove that $G$ is a set, the same holds for $G^{-1}$.

With more details: $G^{-1} = \{ z \mid \exists y \exists x ( z= \{ \{ y \} \{ y,x \} \} \text { and } x \in X \text { and } y \in Y \}$.

But browsing on the textbook, it seems that the author follows a difefrent approach.

If so, IMO you can use Axiom A.3: Every subclass of a set is a set, as well as Th.1.51: If $A,B$ are sets, then $A \times B$ is a set.

Thus, if $G \subseteq X \times Y$ is a set, also $G^{-1} \subseteq Y \times X$ will be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I am missing something but I don't believe the book ever defined a graph such that X and Y had to be sets - merely that it was an arbitrary subclass of U x U (U being the universal class). Otherwise surely all graphs would be sets and specifying this in the problem set would be unnecessary? Instead perhaps I could state that G^-1 is a subset of Ran(G) X Dom(G) which I have already proved to be sets.